# How to query what attributes on an ActiveRecord model are validated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

Is there a way to query which attributes on an ActiveRecord model are validated? Say I have a model like this:

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_numericality_of :age
end

I would like something like this:

> Person.validations
>   => [:name, :age]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
Person.validators.map {|v| v.attributes if v.attributes }.flatten
```